# How to generate summary statistics (similar to psych::describeBy) for subgroups of subgroups, within a larger dataset?

Tags: r, statistics, bioinformatics, biometrics

New to R (for biostats) here! I have a huge dataset, and am using `describe()` and `describeBy()` from the psych package. But I'm also trying to find a way to do basic stats for subgroups within subgroups.

For example, my dataset is about membership within a club, which has Chinese and Indian members. Other variables include gender, age, height, weight, BMI, etcetera.

I have figured out `psych::describeBy` to look at means and standard deviation for subgroups defined by one variable, e.g. ethnicity, but I can't figure out how to narrow this down further so that I generate a summary *only* for Chinese **male** members.

I tried redefining using the `subset()` function, and then running `describeBy` again, e.g.

```
chinese <- subset(maindata, chinese=1)
describeBy(chinese, male=1)
```

But this didn't work, and the results were the same as `describeBy(maindata,chinese=1)`, rather than the Chinese male subset.

I hope that makes sense.

The only other solution I can think of is to breakdown my main dataset into smaller ones in MS Excel and re-uploading each separately (e.g. Chinese.xls, Indian.xls), or to create a new variable with defined by a combination of ethnicity-gender, e.g. Chinesemale=1, Chinesefemale=2, Indianmale=3, Indianfemale=4.

I more or less will need to analyse by these subgroups of subgroups for t-tests and Fisher's exact, so any good package recommendations that would help address these would be appreciated!

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Sample Data**

```
df1 <- data.frame(subject = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5),
                  chinese = c(1, 1, 1, 0, 0),
                  male = c(1, 0, 1, 0, 1),
                  value = c(45, 23, 84, 11, 12))
```

Two changes in syntax from your code:

- double equal sign in `subset()`. You want to keep rows where `chinese` is equal to 1. You would use a single equal sign if you were assigning a value of 1 to a parameter called `chinese`.
- In `describeBy()`, the `group` parameter gives you different summary statistics for each category in that column (as shown below). You can't use it to subset for male=1.

```
chinese <- subset(df1, chinese == 1)

describeBy(chinese, group = "male")

 Descriptive statistics by group 
group: 0
        vars n mean sd median trimmed mad min max range skew kurtosis se
subject    1 1    2 NA      2       2   0   2   2     0   NA       NA NA
chinese    2 1    1 NA      1       1   0   1   1     0   NA       NA NA
male       3 1    0 NA      0       0   0   0   0     0   NA       NA NA
value      4 1   23 NA     23      23   0  23  23     0   NA       NA NA
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
group: 1
        vars n mean    sd median trimmed   mad min max range skew kurtosis   se
subject    1 2  2.0  1.41    2.0     2.0  1.48   1   3     2    0    -2.75  1.0
chinese    2 2  1.0  0.00    1.0     1.0  0.00   1   1     0  NaN      NaN  0.0
male       3 2  1.0  0.00    1.0     1.0  0.00   1   1     0  NaN      NaN  0.0
value      4 2 64.5 27.58   64.5    64.5 28.91  45  84    39    0    -2.75 19.5
```

If you only want to see the summary stats for males in the sample, you could add `& male == 1` to the `subset()`:

```
chinese <- subset(df1, chinese == 1 & male == 1)

describeBy(chinese)

        vars n mean    sd median trimmed   mad min max range skew kurtosis   se
subject    1 2  2.0  1.41    2.0     2.0  1.48   1   3     2    0    -2.75  1.0
chinese    2 2  1.0  0.00    1.0     1.0  0.00   1   1     0  NaN      NaN  0.0
male       3 2  1.0  0.00    1.0     1.0  0.00   1   1     0  NaN      NaN  0.0
value      4 2 64.5 27.58   64.5    64.5 28.91  45  84    39    0    -2.75 19.5
```